# How to add hyperlink in description while creating issue with rest API in jira cloud

Tags: jira, rest

Want to add hyperlink in description while creating issue with rest API in jira cloud.

Answer (score 1):

I've used added hyperlinks to comments and description with rest API, best to use it like this :

```
"example string [link title|http://example.com] "
```